# Akka: Calling setReceiveTimeout while processing a message marked with NotInfluenceReceiveTimeout

Tags: timeout, akka

When using Akka, annotating a message with `NotInfluenceReceiveTimeout` implies that receipt of this message won't reset any timeout previously set (using `setReceiveTimeout`). However, should such a message be received and we trigger a `setReceiveTimeout` call while processing the message, will this call be ignored resulting in no timeout being set?

Answer (score 0):

No.

- the receive timeout logic is implemented with a scheduled `ReceiveTimeout` message to be sent after the designated timeout
- whenever a message is received by the actor, its checked for the `NotInfluenceReceiveTimeout` marker

  - if the message DOES NOT carry the `NotInfluenceReceiveTimeout` marker, the scheduled `ReceiveTimeout` is cancelled, and a new one is rescheduled
  - otherwise, the scheduled message is left untouched
- the message is then processed - regardless of the `NotInfluenceReceiveTimeout` marker. If `setReceiveTimeout` is invoked here, it will be effective even for `NotInfluenceReceiveTimeout` messages.

Check out the source code ([here](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/actor/dungeon/ReceiveTimeout.scala) and [here](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/actor/ActorCell.scala)) for more info.

Comment: I asked the original question since I encountered a corner case in my code where a timeout was not being triggered even if i called `setReceiveTimeout` with a finite duration with no subsequent cancellation. On reviewing the code [here](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/actor/dungeon/ReceiveTimeout.scala) isn't line 32 possibly wrong? What if all messages in the mailbox implement `NotInfluenceReceiveTimeout`? Wouldn't that lead to an incorrect early exit?